# How to use second and third value of split if first value is not present?

Tags: java, arrays, split

I'm trying to create a java class to get the amount of seconds from an HH:mm:ss duration to use in some math and it works. The only problem is, if the user only has minutes and seconds, they wouldn't think to put in, for example, 0:3:42, but they would instead put 3:42.

Here's the code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int seconds = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter time in HH:mm:ss to convert into seconds:");
        String standardTime = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();

        String[] split = standardTime.split(":"); {
            seconds += Integer.parseInt(split[0]) * 3600;
            seconds += Integer.parseInt(split[1]) * 60;
            seconds += Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
        }
        System.out.println(seconds);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use [1] and [2] instead of [0] and [1] if the format is in mm:ss instead of HH:mm:ss.

Comment: You can  split according to standartTime  length

Comment: The instructions state _Enter time in HH:mm:ss..._ Is it an error if the input is not in that format?

Comment: I would advise against this. Keep it simple and throw an input exception with an explanatory message if they mess it up.  In other words, if they don't think of it, explain it to them.

Comment: @AndrewS It is not an error, but it would calculate wrong if the time has no hour and the user doesn't know to put in 0: at the beginning because it's just weird and causes an inconvenience for the user.

Comment: @WJS I would rather provide an easy experience for the user than an easy experience for myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to the indexes from the end of the array instead of the beginning of an array, and assume the value is `0` if the array is too small:

```java
seconds += split.length == 3 ? Integer.parseInt(split[0])*3600 : 0;
seconds += Integer.parseInt(split[split.length - 2])*60;
seconds += Integer.parseInt(split[split.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the input is mm:ss and you call split with ":" as a delimiter, it would essentially create an array with two values - the 'mm' and the 'ss'.

Hence, to read from that array, you should use indices 0 and 1. There's no way to get index 2 from an array with two values (without getting [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)).

Instead, you may check the size of that array once created. If it is 2, then you know you have only minutes and seconds and do the calculation you want to.